# Adding Data tables to COLUMN_CLUSTERED or COLUMN_STACKED charts with Python PPTX

Tags: python-3.x, python-pptx

how to create COLUMN_CLUSTERED or COLUMN_STACKED  charts that include automatically-generated data tables with the legend like below using python-pptx library.

[column clustered chart with data table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pa10M.png)

Comment: Unfortunately, `python-pptx` currently has no API support for this.

Comment: https://github.com/scanny/python-pptx/issues/373 solution mentioned in this link worked.